# nginx hook before upload

Tags: nginx, file-upload, hook

I've created an intranet http site where users can upload their files, I have created a location like this one:

```
location /upload/ {
    limit_except POST          { deny all; }
    client_body_temp_path      /home/nginx/tmp;
    client_body_in_file_only   on;
    client_body_buffer_size    1M;
    client_max_body_size       10G;
    proxy_set_header           X-upload /upload/;
    proxy_set_header           X-File-Name $request_body_file;
    proxy_set_body             $request_body_file;
    proxy_redirect             off;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_pass                 http://localhost:8080/;
}
```

Quite easy as suggested in the official doc. When upload is complete the `proxy_pass` directive calls the custom URI and makes filesystem operations on newly created temp file.

`curl --request POST --data-binary "@myfile.img" http://myhost/upload/`

Here's my problem: I need to have some kind of custom hook/operation telling me when the upload begins, something nginx can call **before** starting the http stream, is there a way to achieve that ? I mean, before uploading big files I need to call a custom url (something like `proxy_pass`) to inform the server about this upload and execute certain operations.

Is there a way to achieve it ? I have tried with echo-nginx module but it didn't succeed with these http POST (binary form-urlencoded). I don't want to use external scripts to deal with the upload and keep these kind of operations inside nginx (more performant)

Thanks in advance.

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self replying.
I have found this directive in order to solve my own request.

`auth_request <something>`

So I can do something like:

```
location /upload/ {
    ...
    # Pre auth
    auth_request /somethingElse/;
    ...
}

# Newly added section
location /somethingElse/ {
    ...
    proxy_pass ...;
}
```

This seems to be fine and working, useful for uploads as well as for general auth or basic prechecks